# Qt Mousebutton is not releasing

Tags: qt, button, release, click, pressed

In my programm it is possible to grab points with the mouse and moving them. The problem is that Qt is not releasing the point after I have released the mousebutton. Isnt there something like:

```
if(Qt::Leftbutton && isPressed(true))
```

I did look on the trolltech website but couldnt find something that woul help

thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Try [mouseReleaseEvent](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#mouseReleaseEvent).